# How to access XMPPRoster from Multiple View Controller classes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmppframework

I am a newbie to iOS app development and am stuck in the middle of nowhere. Here's an explanation of the problem that I am facing. I am trying to implement an Instant Messaging App using the XMPPFramework and the OpenFire server. 
But, I am facing trouble implementing the XMPPRoster functions over multiple view controllers. 
In my main AppDelegate class, I have the following code to initialize XMPPRoster:

**MainAppDelegate.m**

```
xmppRosterStorage = [[XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage alloc] init];
xmppRoster = [[XMPPRoster alloc] initWithRosterStorage:xmppRosterStorage];
xmppRoster.autoFetchRoster = YES;
xmppRoster.autoAcceptKnownPresenceSubscriptionRequests = YES;
xmppvCardStorage = [XMPPvCardCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];
xmppvCardTempModule = [[XMPPvCardTempModule alloc] initWithvCardStorage:xmppvCardStorage];
xmppvCardAvatarModule = [[XMPPvCardAvatarModule alloc] initWithvCardTempModule:xmppvCardTempModule];
xmppCapabilitiesStorage = [XMPPCapabilitiesCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];
xmppCapabilities = [[XMPPCapabilities alloc] initWithCapabilitiesStorage:xmppCapabilitiesStorage];

xmppCapabilities.autoFetchHashedCapabilities = YES;
xmppCapabilities.autoFetchNonHashedCapabilities = NO;

// Activate xmpp modules

[xmppReconnect         activate:xmppStream];
[xmppRoster            activate:xmppStream];
[xmppvCardTempModule   activate:xmppStream];
[xmppvCardAvatarModule activate:xmppStream];
[xmppCapabilities      activate:xmppStream];

// Add ourself as a delegate to anything we may be interested in

[xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[xmppRoster addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    allowSelfSignedCertificates = NO;
allowSSLHostNameMismatch = NO;
```

And then inside the same **MainAppDelegate.m** file, I use the following code to register a user to the roster:

```
 [xmppRoster acceptPresenceSubscriptionRequestFrom:[tmpPresence from] andAddToRoster:YES];
```

The entire code works fine upto this point. However, next I am trying to call the XMPPRoster subscribePresenceToUser function using the following code in **XYZViewController.m** file:

```
[xmppRoster subscribePresenceToUser:(XMPPJID *)friendID];
```

The question that I am facing is do I need to create a new XMPPRoster object instantiation inside XYZViewController.m or is there a way to reuse the xmppRoster instant that I am already using in **MainAppDelegate.m** file (i.e., may be passing this object on or something)?

I have already tried the following in **XYZViewController.m**:

```
 MainAppDelegate *myappdelegate = [[MainAppDelegate alloc] init];
   [myappdelegate.xmppRoster subscribePresenceToUser:(XMPPJID *)friendID];
```

But, seemingly the **subscribePresenceToUser** function inside the XMPPRoster class doesn't even get called. I tested that by inserting a couple of NSLog inside the **subscribePresenceToUser** function. I am completely clueless on this. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.